# showing CircularProgressIndicator until the function end | flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I want to show `CircularProgressIndicator` until the function end, So I use this method,

- `set bool isLoading = false;`
- and this is the function,

  ```
  verifyPhoneNumber(String input) async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    await AuthMethods().phoneSign(context, input);
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });}
  ```
- For this screen

  ```
                Scaffold(
                        body:  
                        isLoading
                            ? Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: darkblueColor),
                              )
                            : Column(
                                children: [ 
                                 IntlPhoneField(
                                      onChanged: (phone) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          fullNumber = phone.completeNumber;
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                 CustomButton(
                                      onTap: () {
                                            verifyPhoneNumber(fullNumber);
                                      },
                                      text: "Next",
                                      height: 50,
                                    ),],),)
  ```

This is not working!. Can `futureBuilder`apply for this & If it's yes, How?

this function work for firebase phoneAuth, There is `phoneSign` inside `AuthMethods` class.

Comment: it is supped to be working, can you include a full sample widget

Comment: another thing, you like to have it on button pressed or directly on futureBuilder?

Comment: I want to call the function when the user complete phone number and press the next button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question snippet , you need to await for `verifyPhoneNumber`

```dart
Future<void> verifyPhoneNumber(String input) async {
  setState(() {
    isLoading = true;
  });
  await AuthMethods().phoneSign(context, input);
  setState(() {
    isLoading = false;
  });}
```

Make the async method

```dart
CustomButton(
   onTap: ()async {
         await verifyPhoneNumber(fullNumber); // you need to await for future
```

Comment: also `await showSnackBar`, use `await` on every future method

Comment: It worked! Thank you for being so supportive. Have a nice day @yeasin

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [async method](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), you already answered your Q. Also I am not sure what is your process but `StreamBuilder` also could be an option.

You make a call

```dart
Future _checkVerifyPhoneNumber() async {
  try {
    bool res = await AuthMethods().phoneSign(context, input);
    return res;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Then you do as the docs say and do something like this

```dart
Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: checkVerifyPhoneNumber(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Column(
                       children: [ 
                         IntlPhoneField(
                          onChanged: (phone) {
                          setState(() {
                           fullNumber = phone.completeNumber;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                            CustomButton(
                                    onTap: () {
                                          verifyPhoneNumber(fullNumber);
                                    },
                                    text: "Next",
                                    height: 50,
                                  ),],),)
                             }
                              else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              const Icon(
                                Icons.error_outline,
                                color: Colors.red,
                                size: 60,
                               );
                          } else {
                              SizedBox(
                               width: 60,
                               height: 60,
                               child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                           ),
                         }
                     }),
                  );
```

Comment: Look nice. But, I want to call _checkVerifyPhoneNumber function when user complete phone number and press the next button. This method, always run the function

Comment: If I understood you right. I think if you press the button maybe it will work, you need to check with your case. But also `streambuilder` might be a better option cuz that will listen and update the widget if the stream data changes

Comment: the issue is gone with above Yeasin Sheikh's answer. Really thank you for your effort. Have a nice day